# Gradle DSL method not found: 'destination()' after update to Gradle 5.2.1

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After updating to Gradle 5.2.1 my build is failing with this error:

`Gradle DSL method not found: 'destination()'`

I figured out that this error has something todo with my `analysis.gradle`

My `analysis.gradle` looks like that

```
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
apply plugin: 'pmd'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {
toolVersion = "0.7.7.201606060606"
}

check.dependsOn 'checkstyle', 'pmd', 'lint'

task checkstyle(type: Checkstyle) {
println "----- checkstyle -----"
configFile file(projectDir.getAbsolutePath() + '/analysis/checkstyle-ruleset.xml')

source 'src'
source '../domain/src'
source '../util/src'
include '**/*.java'
exclude '**/gen/**'
exclude '**/java-gen/**'
exclude '**/androidTest/**'
exclude '**/test/**'

ignoreFailures = true

classpath = files()

reports {
    xml {
        destination buildDir.absolutePath + "/outputs/reports/checkstyle_report.xml"
    }
}
```

}

I think I have to replace the `destination` flag but I have no idea how to replace it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Before Gradle 5.0 the method `setDestination(Object file)` was already deprecated, see here : [setDestination(Object file)](https://docs.gradle.org/4.10/javadoc/org/gradle/api/reporting/ConfigurableReport.html#setDestination-java.lang.Object-)

In Gradle 5.x this method has been removed, you must now use `setDestination(File file)` which takes a `File` parameter (see [setDestination(File file)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/reporting/ConfigurableReport.html#setDestination-java.io.File-) )

So you need to change your code into:

```
reports {
    xml {
        destination file("$buildDir/outputs/reports/checkstyle_report.xml")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I've tried your suggestion out but I've getting this error: Unable to create Root Module: config {/Users/fooUser/Projects/analysis/checkstyle-ruleset.xml}, classpath {null}.

Comment: is this the correct path to your ruleset file ? `/Users/fooUser/Projects/analysis/checkstyle-ruleset.xml`  .It could also be a problem with the config file itself (incompatible version?  you should try with a simple/recent config file, to make sure)

Comment: I've moved my rulesets for checkstyle and pmd from `analysis` folder to `config` folder. Now everything is fine. Thank you a lot.

Comment: I had the exact same issue, this fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

All adjustment was done in my `quality.gradle`. Check config folder for `quality.gradle` file and change all usage of

> destination "$reportsDir/pmd/pmd.xml"

to

> destination file("$reportsDir/pmd/pmd.html")