# Gradle DSL method not found: 'destination()'

Tags: java, android, gradle

I clone source code from github and update **Android studio to 3.5**, **Gradle to 5.4.1**,
It show error `Gradle DSL method not found: 'destination()'` I have tried find answer for error in stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54671249/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-destination-after-update-to-gradle-5-2-1) by add `file` method on `quality.gradle` in `.../config/quality/.` folder.

But It show new error message  
`Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskInputs.file(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/gradle/api/tasks/TaskInputs;'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)`

I can't fix that. Please advise me.

This **quality.gragle** file

```
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
apply plugin: 'findbugs'
apply plugin: 'pmd'

dependencies {
    checkstyle 'com.puppycrawl.tools:checkstyle:6.5'
}

def qualityConfigDir = "$project.rootDir/config/quality";
def reportsDir = "$project.buildDir/reports"

check.dependsOn 'checkstyle', 'findbugs', 'pmd'

task checkstyle(type: Checkstyle, group: 'Verification', description: 'Runs code style checks') {
    configFile file("$qualityConfigDir/checkstyle/checkstyle-config.xml")
    source 'src'
    include '**/*.java'
    exclude '**/model/**'
    exclude '**/AppLogger.java'
    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        xml {
            destination file("$reportsDir/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml")
        }
    }

    classpath = files()
}

task findbugs(type: FindBugs,
        group: 'Verification',
        description: 'Inspect java bytecode for bugs',
        dependsOn: ['compileDebugSources', 'compileReleaseSources']) {

    ignoreFailures = false
    effort = "max"
    reportLevel = "high"
    excludeFilter = new File("$qualityConfigDir/findbugs/android-exclude-filter.xml")
    classes = files("$project.rootDir/app/build/intermediates/classes")

    source 'src'
    include '**/*.java'
    exclude '**/gen/**'

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = false
        xml {
            destination file("$reportsDir/findbugs/findbugs.xml")
        }
        html {
            destination file("$reportsDir/findbugs/findbugs.html")
        }
    }

    classpath = files()
}


task pmd(type: Pmd, group: 'Verification', description: 'Inspect sourcecode for bugs') {
    ruleSetFiles = files("$qualityConfigDir/pmd/pmd-ruleset.xml")
    ignoreFailures = false
    ruleSets = []

    source 'src'
    include '**/*.java'
    exclude '**/gen/**'
    exclude '**/model/**'

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
        xml {
            destination file("$reportsDir/pmd/pmd.xml")
        }
        html {
            destination file("$reportsDir/pmd/pmd.html")
        }
    }
}
```

**build.gradle file (project)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

// Define versions in a single place
ext {
    // Sdk and tools
    minSdkVersion = 16
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'

    // App dependencies
    supportLibraryVersion = '26.1.0'
    gsonVersion = '2.8.0'
    calligraphyVersion = '2.2.0'
    glideVersion = '3.7.0'

    rx2FastAndroidNetworking = '1.0.1'

    dagger2Version = '2.8'
    rxjava2Version = '2.0.6'
    rxandroidVersion = '2.0.1'
    butterKnifeVersion = '8.6.0'
    greenDaoVersion = '3.2.0'
    placeholderviewVersion = '0.6.1'
    debugDBVersion = '1.0.3'
    timberVersion = '4.5.1'

    //Test dependencies
    junitVersion = '4.12'
    espressoVersion = '2.2.2'
    mockitoVersion = '2.7.1'
}
```

**build.gradle file (app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'org.greenrobot.greendao'
apply from: '../config/quality/quality.gradle'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mindorks.framework.mvp"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL", "\"http://www.mocky.io/v2\"")
            buildConfigField("String", "API_KEY", "\"ABCXYZ123TEST\"")
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL", "\"http://www.mocky.io/v2\"")
            buildConfigField("String", "API_KEY", "\"ABCXYZ123TEST\"")
        }
    }
}

greendao {
    schemaVersion 1
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    // android support libraries
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"

    // font
    implementation "uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:$rootProject.calligraphyVersion"

    // network
    implementation "com.amitshekhar.android:rx2-android-networking:$rootProject.rx2FastAndroidNetworking"

    // image
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$rootProject.glideVersion"

    // parser
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$rootProject.gsonVersion"

    // database
    implementation "org.greenrobot:greendao:$rootProject.greenDaoVersion"

    // debug database
    debugImplementation "com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:$rootProject.debugDBVersion"

    // dependency injection
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
    compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'

    // reactive
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rootProject.rxjava2Version"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rootProject.rxandroidVersion"

    // code generator for view
    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$rootProject.butterKnifeVersion"
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$rootProject.butterKnifeVersion"

    // swipe view
    implementation "com.mindorks:placeholderview:$rootProject.placeholderviewVersion"

    // logger
    implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:$rootProject.timberVersion"

    // dependencies for local unit tests
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$rootProject.ext.junitVersion"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:$rootProject.mockitoVersion"
    testAnnotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.dagger2Version"

    // UI Testing
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$rootProject.espressoVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$rootProject.espressoVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:$rootProject.mockitoVersion"
    androidTestAnnotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportLibraryVersion"
}
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```